# ShareThis - Buttons loaded after AJAX content not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, social-networking, expressionengine

The site is built with ExpressionEngine (2.8.1), but because the content to be shared is loaded via AJAX I decided to use the generated code for "Website" on the ShareThis website rather than the probably outdated EE add-on.

So ShareThis generated the following markup, which I have placed in the EE template that is loaded via AJAX:

```
<span class="st_facebook_large" displayText="Facebook"></span>
<span class="st_twitter_large" displayText="Tweet"></span>
<span class="st_pinterest_large" displayText="Pinterest"></span>
<span class="st_googleplus_large" displayText="Google +"></span>
<span class="st_email_large" displayText="Email"></span>
```

In the header I am loading the scripts as provided:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var switchTo5x=true;</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher: "MY_PUBLISHER_ID", doNotHash: false, doNotCopy: false, hashAddressBar: false});</script>
```

Then in the JS I have the following script bound to the click event that loads the content:

```
$('#ajax-content').load('ajax/'+id, function() {
    if(window.stButtons) {
        stButtons.locateElements();
    }
}
```

However, while the buttons are generated properly, they don't seem to have any event handlers bound to them; clicking them does nothing. I've tried without checking `if(window.stButtons)`, but it makes no difference.

If instead of `stButtons.locateElements();` I use the following code, the buttons do not even show up:

```
$.getScript('http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js', function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
    var switchTo5x = true;
    stLight.options({publisher: "MY_PUBLISHER_ID", doNotHash: false, doNotCopy: false, hashAddressBar: false});
});
```

Any ideas what's going wrong and what I can do to get it working?

Answer (score 1):

Click Events only work on content loaded by the DOM. If you add content after the DOM has been loaded, then these elements will not have the Click-event on them.

To solve this you need to use [jQuery Delegate Function](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/). Which also works on "Future Elements", meaning elements that have been loaded afterwards by using for example Ajax.

Comment: I figured as much, but how can I use Delegate if I don't know the function that ShareThis is calling on the click event? Besides, I thought re-initializing the buttons after the content was loaded would establish the handlers on the new content.

Comment: Sorry, nevermind, I realized the script was working fine but my CSS was literally blocking click events on the buttons.